# Plotly.js : data seems ok, but scatter plot remains empty

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am using plotly.js and am trying to display live gathered metrics.
For now I am using a setInterval() function to add data to the plot (easier to debug), and I update the plot with https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyupdate.

After each call of Plotly.update(myDiv, data, layout, [0, 1]), I call myDiv.data and print the result. It seems to work well :

[console screendshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr0oW.png)

Yet my plot remains empty...

Any idea ?

I am using the following Plotly config :

```
 layout = {
     xaxis: {
         autorange: true,
         zeroline: true,
         zerolinecolor: 'white',
         linecolor: 'white',
         tickfont: {
             color: 'white'
         }
     },
     yaxis: {
         autorange: true,
         zeroline: true,
         zerolinecolor: 'white',
         linecolor: 'white',
         tickfont: {
             color: 'white'
         }
     },
     width: w,
     height: h,
     margin: {
         l: 25,
         r: 10,
         b: 25,
         t: 15
     },
     paper_bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
     plot_bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
 };
```

and data.mode = 'scatter'

I even tried adding 'fake' data to the plot's arrays (x and y) so it's not empty at start time, but even like this my plot remains empty.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you just got the data format wrong. It's not [Array, Array, Array] but [trace, trace, tace]. Just that.

```js
const trace1 = {
    name: "buffer",
    x: [60.807, 62.806, 64.814, 66.81, 80.805],
    y: [100, 87, 100, 30, 80],
    mode: "scatter",
    type: "scatter"
}

const trace2 = {
    name: "latency",
    x: [64.814, 66.809, 80.804, 140.806, 200.816],
    y: [41.2513, 79.0122, 45.3155, 55.253, 47.278],
    mode: "scatter",
    type: "scatter"
}

const layout = {
    xaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        zeroline: true,
        zerolinecolor: 'white',
        linecolor: 'white',
        tickfont: {
            color: 'white'
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        autorange: true,
        zeroline: true,
        zerolinecolor: 'white',
        linecolor: 'white',
        tickfont: {
            color: 'white'
        }
    },
    // width: w,
    // height: h,
    margin: {
        l: 25,
        r: 10,
        b: 25,
        t: 15
    },
    paper_bgcolor: 'transparent',
    plot_bgcolor: 'transparent'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2]

Plotly.newPlot(document.querySelector("#plot"), data, layout, [0, 1])
```

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: black !important;
}

.flex-container-center {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#plot {
    width: 750px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.x.x/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.27.0.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex-container-center h-100">
    <div id="plot"></div>
</div>
```